# The battle really between all these vaccines is going to

Tags: word-usage

Does the word "really" in the phrase "The battle **really** between all these vaccines is going to" sound odd to you? Should it be removed?

> And more of the vaccine may be available sooner, relative to other jabs. AstraZeneca estimates that it will have 200 million doses ready worldwide by the end of 2020 and capacity to produce 100 million to 200 million doses per month once production is ramped up, according to Pam Cheng, vice-president for operations and information technology at AstraZeneca.

> “**The battle really between all these vaccines is going to** be really a logistical one,” says Vandenberghe. “We will be able to use every dose that becomes available.”

> Source:  Nature    [Why Oxford’s positive COVID vaccine results are puzzling scientists](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03326-w)

Comment: The quote is of someone getting a bit tangled up in framing an answer. “Really” is a mistake pure and simple and should not be in the sentence at that spot. The second one is the intended placement.